# Using nested for loop and checking if the number is even or odd

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a code to check for Bipolar-RZ. Where if you get a 0, there is nothing happening but if there's 1 then transition happens in the middle from positive voltage to 0 and then from negative voltage to 0 voltage.
So the way I approached this was if for example you have `b=[0 1 0 1 1 0 1]`. You calculate how many ones u have. Then you put those ones in the for loop and add them. Then you use if statement to check for if the number of ones after adding is even or odd and then you transition.
The problem is that I'm using another for loop and the for loop (to check for even and odd) goes into the other for loop.

Also to use iseven and isodd, I searched online. They have the code in MATLAB. Otherwise that function doesnt work. Here is the link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35105-isevenisodd

I would be really great full if someone replies.
Thank You

```
% for ibs, I'm using ibs=[0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]

function output = lc_bi(ibs,tlc, Rb)

output=1;
numofbits=length(ibs);


%  Bipolar RZ coding

if isequal(tlc,'RZ')

    %for loop to calculate 1's
    y=0;
    for k=1:length(ibs)
        if ibs(k)==1
            y=y+1;
        end
    end

    oness=ones(1,y); %converting it in to list of ones


    samptime= 0.001;
    endtime= numofbits-samptime;
    t=0:samptime:endtime; 

    cycle= floor(length(t)/(numofbits-1));
    j=1;

    tran_in_middle= j+cycle/2;

    bit=1;
    for i=0:samptime:endtime
        if (floor(i)+1 ~=bit)
            tran_in_middle=j+cycle/2;
            bit=bit+1;
        end

        if (ibs(bit)==1)
            if(j< tran_in_middle)

                %put the loop her to check if itseven or odd
                %using the list of ones here and adding them to check for even and odd
                g=0;
                for h=1:length(oness)
                    g=g+1;
                    if isodd(g)==true
                        s(j) =Rb;
                        disp('+')
                    elseif isodd(g)==false

                        s(j)=-Rb;
                        disp('-')
                    end
                end
            else
                s(j) = 0;
            end

        end
        j=j+1;
    end

    plot(t,s);
    axis([0 numofbits -(Rb+1) (Rb+1)]);
    xlabel ('Time');
    ylabel ('Voltage');

end
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here but no indication of where the problem is. It's also tough to decipher what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could provide a sample output for your sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment rather than answer ...

I don't understand either your code or your question but from what you've shown us I am concerned that you're not 'getting' Matlab at all.  For example the code

```
%for loop to calculate 1's
y=0;
for k=1:length(ibs)
    if ibs(k)==1
        y=y+1;
    end
end
```

seems to be a laborious way to compute

```
y = sum(ibs)
```

I suspect, though I'm not sure, that the other loops in your code could be replaced in similar vein and that you should study some of the basic documentation in more depth.  While languages such as C require the programmer to write loops to iterate over vectors and arrays Matlab provides an extensive collection of functions which work on arrays. `sum` is just one  basic example.

Statements such as

```
if isodd(g)==true
```

concern me too.  In Matlab, and any other programming language I have ever worked with, that is a long-winded way of writing

```
if isodd(g)
```

I'm not too concerned that you might write long-winded code, but your original construction is one that raises the suspicion, supported by my experience of junior and not-professionally-trained programmers, that you are not quite 'getting' booleans.

You then write the other branch of the `if` statement as

```
elseif isodd(g)==false
```

Since you're setting `g` to an integer value there is no need for an `elseif` at all, the only possibility, if `g` is not odd is that `g` is even, so you can replace that statement with the briefer and clearer

```
else
```

I think you should rewrite your code entirely and write it **in** Matlab; what you have so far might be C written **with** Matlab.

Comment: I think the mentioned by you loop is `y = sum(ibs==1)` rather than just sum (if `ibs` is not boolean).

Comment: By OP's definition `ibs` contains only `0`s and `1`s so the test for equality is unnecessary and it's a moot point whether it makes the code easier to understand.  I don't think it does.